# Position cursor after element when inserting into contenteditable?

Tags: contenteditable

I want to be able to insert images, wrapped in a span, into a contenteditable div. I can do this no problem but then when I go to type, after the image, it inserts my text into the images span. How do I position the cursor AFTER the span that I just inserted?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/s7hhdm46/) is my fiddle (click "Add Image at Cursor" and the enter text into the content editable. Observe the text is inside the images parent span.)

Here is my image insert function:

```
function insertElementAtCursor(elm) {
    var sel, range, html;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(elm);
            placeCaretAfterNode(elm);
            updateTextArea();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Added a text node after the span and moved the range to that](http://jsfiddle.net/s7hhdm46/4/)

```
function insertElementAtCursor(elm) {
    var sel, range, html;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(elm);

            var textNode = document.createTextNode('\u00A0');
            range.setStartAfter(elm);
            range.insertNode(textNode);
            range.setStartAfter(textNode);
            range.collapse(true);
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
```